# "Fusion Drive" on eOS?

Tags: release-juno, disk-management

I have an HP Stream 11 on which I hope to install elementary OS. I got Juno and successfully installed it, but the drive on the Stream is so tiny I had to wipe Windows out and install elementary OS alone. Worked fine except the WiFi (*separate question*).

I had to reinstall Windows to restore WiFi. Since reinstalling Windows I received a 256GB micro SD that now lives in the Stream's micro SD slot. I'm actually quite pleased with the way Windows is automatically managing that additional storage. Seems to be working very similar to how my "fusion" drive works on my Mac.

Will elementary OS (or any Linux installation) do the same, or will I have to be careful about selecting where exactly I install program files, i.e., on the C: drive or D: drive?

I use this computer for very limited purposes, there will be few applications installed, mostly data files. Will elementary OS automatically install applications on, and run them from, the D: drive transparently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you call Fusion Drive in Linux is called, for a long time, Logical Volume Management (LVM)

[image: lvm]

Watch this video I just found (at least the first 6 minutes)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fadQX2e_PGk

To explain it easily enough... imagine you have three hard drives and you want the system to see them as one, with LVM you do that creating a volume group...that volume group (VG) is that huge "disk" and from that VG you create logical volumes (LV) that can be like creating partitions but in this case is from a logical abstraction VG

In your case the only issue I see is in case the sdcard comes late and that produce errors. But try it maybe it doesn't happen at all